# Bootstrap 3 - Control a Nav Panel with 2 Identical Nav Tabs - Update active class for both

Tags: jquery, tabs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have bootstrap tabs set up, but would like to have multiple nav-tabs to control one nav pane — A set of nav-tabs at the top, and below the tab pane. The below code works if I click in nav-tabs 2, but doesn't update nav-tabs 1 with the correct 'active tab'.

Would anyone know how to achieve this? thanks!

```
<!-- Nav tabs 1-->
<div class="centered-pills">    
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
  <li class="active"><a href="#a" data-toggle="tab"><span>Style</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#b" data-toggle="tab"><span>b</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#c" data-toggle="tab"><span>c</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div> <!-- end centered-pills -->

<div class="tab-content">
<div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="a"></div>
<div class="tab-pane fade in" id="b"></div>
<div class="tab-pane fade in" id="b"></div>
</div> <!-- end tab-content -->

 <!-- Nav tabs 2-->
<div class="centered-pills">    
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
  <li class="active"><a href="#a" data-toggle="tab"><span>Style</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#b" data-toggle="tab"><span>b</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#c" data-toggle="tab"><span>c</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div> <!-- end centered-pills -->
```

Answer (score 0):

This ended up working for me

```
$(document).ready(function() {
if(location.hash) {
   $('a[href=' + location.hash + ']').tab('show');
}
$(document.body).on("click", "a[data-toggle]", function(event) {
location.hash = this.getAttribute("href");
});
});
$(window).on('popstate', function() {
var anchor = location.hash || $("a[data-toggle=tab]").first().attr("href");
$('a[href=' + anchor + ']').tab('show');
});
```